# Android EditText gradient shadow

Tags: android, android-edittext, gradient, shadow, dropshadow

[image: this is What I want, shadow is gradient]

I want a shadow which must have a GRADIENT shadow as shown in image, zoom image to see actual gradient effect[image]

[image]

2nd image is about show effect in zoom

Comment: use layer-list drawable

Comment: no any other option???
because I need to use 10 layers, and still it will not be perfect

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html). Here is, I think, What you want.

Comment: @WaqarKhan elevation is enough to create shadow, but It shows shadow towards left...I want shadow towards right side, right bottom..

Comment: Post your code so that I can check what are you doing.

Comment: @WaqarKhan elevation is useful only for Android 5.0 no??
But my app could use from android 3.0..I need to give support minsdk Android 3.0

Answer (score 0):

all I can see from the picture - you should use [layer-list drawable with 9-patch shadow] for every [state drawable] of the EditText.

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/using-styles-and-themes-in-android/ - you have to read that to get the "selector" drawable that is used for your default, "not styled" EditText.  Then - goto your "android-sdk" folder, find the selector file of corresponding platform (android-14, android-19 etc.). Copy the selector file and all the mentioned "@drawable" .png files that are there. Do that for all dpi-folders respectively. Then edit all the .png files - add your custom shadow. Reference the selector to your new .png-s. Set the selector as background to your EditText (or from Theme). That's all.

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/android-styles-and-themes-tutorial - how to style views. And yes, there is a lot of work - from 6 to 81 .png to edit. Don't forget that all .png-s of the same dpi-folder must have the same width, height and 9-patch rim-lines - otherwise you can obtain "artefacts"

Answer (score 0):

This is finally I got an answer..but Im not satisfied with this answer...so any one have any better solution???

```
        <!-- most important is order of layers -->


        <!-- Bottom right side 1dp Shadow -->
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/lighter_gray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

          <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
        <item
            android:bottom="1px"
            android:right="1px">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/light_gray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

      <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
        <item
            android:bottom="3px"
            android:right="3px">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <!-- White Top color -->
        <item
            android:bottom="5px"
            android:right="5px">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/selector_color" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

**EditText**

```
<EditText style="@style/match_width"
android:background="@drawable/border_with_shadow"
android:hint="Enter Order number"
android:padding="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="11dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: this is my editText :  
    <EditText
     style="@style/match_width"
     android:background="@drawable/border_with_shadow"
     android:hint="Enter Order number"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:paddingLeft="11dp"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="16sp" />

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is my output]

this is my output edittext which is not expected..I expect more accurate